# Is it possible to specify Type to collection property in RDF

Tags: rdf, owl

While specifying the schema in RDF, how can one specify the type of the collection? E.g., I have a property called `hobbies`. There can be more than one `hobbies`. It is also required that the each member in the list must be an instance of class `Hobby`. Though I can specify something like -

```
myschema:hobbies 
  a            rdf:Property;
  rdfs:domain  myschema:Student;
  rdfs:range   rdf:bag 
  .
```

How can I specify that each member in this collection must be of type `myschema:Hobby`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

> How can I specify that each member in this collection must be of type myschema:Hobby?

With RDF/RDFS alone, you can't. You can do it with OWL for instance:

```
myschema:hobbies
  a  rdf:Property;
  rdfs:range  rdf:Bag, [
     a  owl:Restriction;
     owl:onProperty  rdfs:member;
     owl:allValuesFrom  myschema:Hobby
  ] .
```

This is not in OWL DL, however. Why do you need `hobbies` to relate to a `rdf:Bag`? Except in very special and rare situations, it is almost always better to simply have a property that relates to the members directly like so:

```
myschema:hobby
  a  rdf:Property;
  rdfs:range  myschema:Hobby .
```

Then you can still relate a thing to a set of hobbies like this:

```
_:something  myschema:hobby  :hobby1, :hobby2, :hobby3 .
```

In fact, the problem you are asking about is perhaps just a new problem you are creating by having chosen the wrong design. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @antoine-zimmermann. I am beginner here. Having my large experience in java, I thought I can specify a property to be a typed  collection. I was not aware that a property holding list need not be specified as collection/bag. So I wanted to specify that way. Will go with your recommendation and let you know how it goes.

Comment: if i'm trying to author & model a useful hobbies object in my programming environment, i need to be able to query & understand the shape of hobbies. many other tools can describe the shape of datastructures, and if this is the only way rdf can do so, then it's what we need. by the way, antoine, what syntax are you writing your examples in?

Comment: @rektide, I'm wirting the examples in [Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/). RDF and OWL do not describe the shape of data structures at all. If you want to describe the shape of an RDF graph, you should use [SHACL](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/).

Comment: The difference of this approach to a Java `List<Hoppy>`, i that this is actually more like a `Set<Hobby>`, as there is no order to the items in this way.